# Обновил Android Studio. Стала писать Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3

Tags: android

Выдает следующее:
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle: 1.2.3.
>        Required by:
>            :XXX:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/ com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.2.3/gradle-1.2.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/ 1.2.3/gradle-1.2.3.pom'.
>   Connection to https:// jcenter.bintray.com refused

Содержание build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: в buld.gradle в корне проекта напишите вместо: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3` - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

Comment: Снова я) Теперь то же самое пишет, но для 1.3.0. И прокси проверял, все равно ругается.

Comment: Ну а через браузер к `https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.2.3/` есть доступ? Вообще там написано, что не может получить файлы с jcenter

Comment: build.gradle из корня проекта добавьте в вопрос, если не трудно.

Comment: выложил, но теперь ругается и на 1.3.0) заметил, что это началось после обновления студии. дома на старом все работает.